# What is the syntax for selecting an element in protractor via element name

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is it possible to get an element by its name like you can with jQuery?
I'm trying to do the equivalent of the jQuery selector like in jQuery

```
$('h1')
```

how is this done with protractor?

I tried

```
element('h1')
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: angular.element('h1') ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this - you can either get it by tagName or by css selector. So any of the following work:

```
element(by.css('h1')); // works with any css selector
$('h1'); // works with any css selector
element(by.tagName('h1'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally caught that in the tests for protractor

Comment: is the same works for custom html tags (tags which are created by directives ) ?

Answer (score 19):

The answer was finally found on [github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/basic/elements_spec.js) they have a test file that shows all the selectors

```
element(by.css('h1'));
element(by.css('.my-class'));
```

Comment: Have substituted a similar enough test.